# No logfile when combining Robocopy with Task Scheduler

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks, robocopy

I am trying to create a .bat file with Robocopy and schedule it using Task Scheduler in Windows 7. The issue that I am having is with the creation of the log file. When I click on the .bat file, a log file is created. When it runs using Task Scheduler no log file is created.

File copying works in both cases. Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you please post your robocopy command line(s) and maybe a screenshot how you entered the parameters in your scheduled task?

Comment: robocopy "\\XXXXXXXX\PROGRAMS\PRODUCT" "C:\XXXX\XXXXX\Desktop\XXXX\XXXX" /copyALL /tee /s /r:1 /log:"C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\XXXX\Backup Log.TXT"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add

```
>> c:\log.txt
```

to the end of the command which should output any errors to a logfile.